# Rationale behind difference between unique and non-unique indexes in MySQL InnoDB next-key locking

Tags: mysql, locking, innodb

MySQL InnoDB uses next-key locking on non-unique indexes in transactions whereby both the gap before and after the scanned index(es) are locked (which btw the MySQL manual fails to convey in a clear manner, the manual page on next-key locks says that only the gap preceding the scanned index(es) is locked: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-record-level-locks.html).

However, I fail to understand the entire rationale behind this...

Used setup:

```
CREATE TABLE test (a int, b int, index (a));
INSERT INTO test VALUES (5,5), (10,10), (15,15);
```

First client to connect starts transaction A and issues the following `UPDATE` query:

```
UPDATE test set b = 10 where a = 10;
```

Running the following queries from next incoming connection starting transaction B gives the following results:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES(5,5); //On hold
INSERT INTO test VALUES(9,9); //On hold
INSERT INTO test VALUES(14,14); //On hold
INSERT INTO test VALUES(4,4); //Works
INSERT INTO test VALUES 15,15); //Works
UPDATE test SET a = 1 WHERE a = 5; //Works
UPDATE test SET a = 8 WHERE a = 5; //On hold
UPDATE test SET a = 7 WHERE a = 15; //On hold
UPDATE test SET a = 100 WHERE a = 15; //Works
```

It appears transaction B cannot insert rows where a is [5,15) (5 incl. - 15 excl.) nor modify existing rows and set a to be (5, 15) (5 excl. - 15 excl.).

Now, changing the column `a` to have a `PRIMARY KEY` instead:

```
ALTER TABLE test DROP INDEX a;
ALTER TABLE test ADD PRIMARY KEY (a);
```

Redoing the above running in transaction B now gives the following results (insertions to row 5 and 15 gives an error about duplicate key which is why they're not included):

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES(9,9); //Works
INSERT INTO test VALUES(14,14); //Works
INSERT INTO test VALUES(4,4); //Works
INSERT INTO test VALUES(10,10); //On hold
UPDATE test SET a = 1 WHERE a = 5; //Works
UPDATE test SET a = 8 WHERE a = 5; //Works
UPDATE test SET a = 7 WHERE a = 15; //Works
UPDATE test SET a = 100 WHERE a = 15; //Works
UPDATE test SET a = 10 WHERE a = 15; //On hold
UPDATE test SET a = 100 WHERE a = 10; //On hold
```

The behaviour with a primary key seems totally comprehensible and I don't question it (even though the lack of gap locks, using the rationale behind using gap locks to prevent phantom reads, wouldn't prevent phantom reads). I don't question this behaviour at all, I just have a hard time understanding the way regular indexes are dealt with and why they are dealt with in different ways).

Questions:

1. Is the reason for using next-key locks that we want to **prevent phantom reads** (which seems to imply adhering to the rule that a `SELECT` query shouldn't return different results throughout a transaction in isolation level `REPEATABLE READ`) or is it because InnoDB deduces that the **user might want to make an insertion close to the result of the query** (which would then be a heuristic service to the user)? A third reason might be that the overall system principle seems to be to **lock whatever rows that the query results in** and that InnoDB does this without consideration (which would then adhere to some overall principle about rules for concurrency). From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-next-key-locking.html it seems that next-key locking is used to prevent phantom reads only when the `WHERE`clause has a condition like `a > 10` where it would make sense, but if so, why is next-key locking applied as well when the `WHERE` clause is specificly addressing certain rows? Maybe there are several disjunct reasons?
2. Given the reason for next-key locking, why is it necessary to have a different behaviour when the column has a unique versus a non-unique index? At least the first two reasons suggested above don't seem to call for this even though the third might if InnoDB has to search more rows when the column has a non-unique index. Otherwise, to me, it seems as likely that one would want to insert a close-by row no matter if the column has a non-unique index or a unique index... On the other hand, when updating a row, there is no reason to believe that the user would want to insert a row close by so why not lock the entire table why you're at it...?
3. Why does row `a = 5` get locked for `INSERT` but not for `UPDATE`? It's as though there are two lock principles at play at the same time, one that locks modification of existing rows and one that locks insertions and that the existing row `a = 5` is not locked but the insertion of row `a = 5` is locked. Is this correct and if so, why is index 5 included in the gap lock for insertions?

My version of MySQL is `5.5.24` and I used the default isolation level `REPEATABLE READ`.

Answer (score 1):

Your questions are too many. :)

I'm not a database expert and I just give you some hints.

a). index constraint is not necessarily a uniqueness one. MySQL uses gap locks when the condition columns have no index or not a uniqueness one. Because primary key is a uniqueness index, so it just locks the selected records.

b). when you update the index column, actually the records need to reindex. Because innodb uses the clustered index, which means that the record is at the leaf of the primary index B+ tree. So when it needs to find a position to place the updated index node, the database needs to grant the lock request.

```
UPDATE test SET a = 10 WHERE a = 15; //On hold
```

There is no lock at a = 15, but when you'd like to place the index at a =10, where there is a existing lock. So it holds.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! a) is just a restatement of how it is, WHY is it like this? On the webpage they relate it to phantom reads but it seems like it could just as well be because of how MySQL works internally; it needs to lock down rows to deal with consistency... it's all blurry to me :)

Comment: b) is more interesting... however, the clustered index is just at work when I have no index right? In this case I DO have an index on a. Nevertheless, so you mean to say that MySQL keeps the indexes in a certain order and when I make a change to index 10, MySQL might have to need to reorder where it keeps that index, since I'm setting A to 10 (the same as previous, but MySQL wouldn't know), it needs the surroundings of A to be kept still until it has inserted the new index...

Comment: ... and therefore it uses a gap lock, and in the case of a unique index, the internal storage is different and then doesn't require MySQL to lock down the surrounding rows? If this is the case, I don't understand why they keep going on about phantom rows in this context in the manual...

Comment: @fast-reflexes yes, official reference seems to mention everything, but is lack of examples and further in-depth explanations. Sorry for my hurry answer. I'm asking a MySQL expert who is familiar with MySQL source code and how to implement internally. Once I get the details, I'll edit my answer later.

Comment: @fast-reflexes In you case using primary key, all can be explained well. You know, clustered index is the synonym of primary key. So this case has no gap lock, just locks the selected record that is a=10. so the 3 holds are expected.

Comment: Haha, I'd be DELIGHTED to hear the answer :) Also, you're right, clustered index is typically synonymous with primary key but in this document, it refers to an index created by MySQL if no other indexes are present (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-record-level-locks.html). That's what I was thinking about...

Comment: @fast-reflexes There is only one clustered index and it always exist s even you create no index. When you specify a primary key, it uses that. If not, it creates a hidden one for you. Secondary indexes can be multiple, and don't hold the row data but a pointer to the clustered index. when locking in secondary record-index, actually the selected records in clustered index also have locks.